# Easily update HTML table by hand

Tags: html, wysiwyg, table

I have 14 static web pages with large HTML tables on each page that need to be updated by hand frequently (during peak times, this could be multiple times per day, but on average it's more like twice per week).

Currently, I have the data stored in an Excel spreadsheet and I've written some monstrous expressions that generate the HTML code for me. I then take the html files and upload them via FTP to a web server.

However, this is extremely inflexible and makes structural changes to the table (i.e. adding a new column) very time-consuming.

The purpose of these web pages is to display the data set in a simple, clean format to non-technical users. My current end product has had very good reception from users but is very time-consuming to update.

Currently, these pages would only be updated by me or a person in my position (with at least functional knowledge of HTML/CSS/JS & FTP). I think a WYSIWYG that allowed me to edit the table in the preview mode would do the trick.

However, from my understanding, I would need so set up some sort of web form with an embedded WYSIWYG editor to update my pages. I'd rather not build this from scratch if I don't have to, but would prefer not to install large content management systems (like WordPress)

What (preferably lightweight) software can I use to easily update these tables?

Comment: If you are OK with generating HTML and uploading it yourself, and your only issue is that your current HTML generation scheme is brittle, how about having Excel generate the HTML for you (using Save As...)?

Comment: I'd rather check into having Excel export the stuff to e.g. CSV, use an HTML template, and have a script generating the table. Explaining how to do that would be beyond the scope of SR – but you could check with other sources to follow this approach (if it would fit you). See the `/help/on-topic` pages of e.g. SuperUser and SO whether that might fit there (and how you should ask it on those sites). Just a hint :)

Comment: @Izzy: Indeed, if you're going to resort to scripting, you don't really need to export to CSV these days (there are competent Excel-reading libraries for a number of languages), and I don't think there's particular benefit to an explicit HTML template (versus plain old string concatenation/interpolation provided by the scripting language), especially since one of the goals seems to be flexibility in the face of structural changes. The whole project, including uploading the HTML to the hosting site, would make a nice scripting exercise.

Comment: It would certainly, @JohnY – but a template might still be needed to match the look to the site ;)

Comment: I'm not a Web programmer, so maybe I have a nonstandard concept of what "HTML template" entails. In any case, the way OP described their current workflow, it seemed like styling issues were not a concern (either the styling is very rudimentary, or it's trivial to "plug in" the necessary styling from external CSS; if that external CSS *is* an "HTML template", then yeah, that would be helpful, but they would already have it).